# calculate back date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I want to calculate back date.

For example if I am giving 5 months then it should return the 5 month back date and if i give 5 years then it should return the 5 years back date keeping leap year in mind.i tried to implement some of the examples which I found in web but non of them are giving me the exact result.
Can someone please help me to achieve so.

Comment: These the way to go for these kind of calculations is using a library, similar to [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: sorry but I don't want to use any library

Comment: "i tried to implement some of the examples" show us what have you tried?

Comment: @vickey why not? That's what libraries are for, to make common jobs easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [setFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) on a Date object easily.

The thing is, if you're adding a whole year, and it's a leap year, you'll still end on the same date (month and day) of the last year. which i think it's the correct behaviour.

```
now = new Date() // 2016-11-24T13:21:55.841Z
now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() -1) // 2015-11-24T13:21:55.841Z
```

If you want to subtract a standard-sized-year, I think you should instead remove 365 days from the current day. Which will take you to a slightly different date.

```
now = new Date() // 2016-11-24T13:21:55.841Z
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 365) // 2015-11-25T13:21:55.841Z
```

Comment: Hi, I also want to consider the leap year if I am checking date for 5 years ago

Comment: the Date class will take care of that. Can you make an example where it wouldn't return what you expect?

Comment: i am not sure what exact date it will return, this is what I am trying http://jsfiddle.net/2YkeK/1403/

Comment: that's because you're also explicitly setting the date and month to match the current one. just run the code in the examples i posted

Comment: I already tried that but its returning in some integer, please check it if I am wrong format.http://jsfiddle.net/2YkeK/1404/

Comment: it does return an integer (the timestamp of the new date) but it also modify the date object, try logging it to the console to see the new date

Comment: In console also its returning the same format(1322143029216).Can you please do the same in the fiddler example i have provided

Comment: thanks its working now,but what if leap year comes in between

Comment: as I said, adding one year, will take you to the same day and month of next year. adding 365 days is a different matter, and the result depends upon leap years and such. it all depends on what you expect